# Strict Standards Pear error with Jobberbase 2.0

Tags: php, caching, pear, php-5.6

Fresh "Jobberbase 2.0" install on shared hosting, support desk is closed for hours, so I'll ask here in hopes of someone knowing what this is, better than I do, which is zero to none.

It's the same bug that's detailed here:

https://github.com/filipcte/jobberbase/issues/11

I tried what their solution was to no avail, as it's vague to me. I tried the same filename from PEAR current, which has a different line just 1 line before the one called into question in my error.

3 Screenshots of what I'm encountering:

http://imgur.com/tgsxVSj,uCWak31,b7ig83S

When I click on any of the 3 submenus this is my error:

Deprecated: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/funkysal/public_html/_lib/CacheLite/Lite.php on line 538

I'm at a loss & appreciate any direction I can come by from users here.

Thanks much,

-C

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by either upgrading to PEAR 1.10.0dev2, which fixes those E_STRICT errors, or by hiding E_STRICT errors:

```
<?php error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); ?>
```